# ActiveCell Based Selection

Tags: excel, vba

Column `A` to `H` has data with some blanks in between. I want to find "ABC" in column `A` and then select 2 rows above - this will be my `ActiveCell`.

I want to delete rows in between `ActiveCell` to `Row2` (Active Cell is Dynamic)

```
Sub format()   
    Cells.Find(What:="abc", _
               After:=ActiveCell, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               LookAt:= xlPart, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, _
               SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell, A2).Select   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Range` please try:

```
 (ActiveCell, "A2").Select
```

Comment: I think that's how you select Range between `Activecell` and `row2` as user asked.

Comment: What could be missing code to run this code in all sheets within the workbook?

Comment: Sub formatFinal()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For Each ws In Worksheets

    Cells.Find(What:="abc", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, "A2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Next
    Next ws



End Sub

Answer (score 1):

**The code will do the job for you:**

```
Sub format()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="abc", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False)

    rng.Offset(-2, 0).Select

    Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(2, 1)).Select
    'Selection.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Currently I have commented out the last line which will delete the Rows you want. uncomment it, but first be sure that's what you want to delete.